# WPF: get the exact size of a line in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I would like to place controls on each line of a RichTextBox - something like that:

```
---------------------------------
| Control1 | This is a multiline|
| Control2 | Richtextbox and I  |
| Control3 | want to place a    |
| Control4 | control excactly   |
| Control5 | beside each line.  |
---------------------------------
```

So I want to place a Control on the left of each line. I guess I have to find out the actual height of each line and place the controls accordingly. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What's your functional need ? Stated like that, it seems almost impossibel to achieve. There are not many methods that will help you do that on RichTextBox and FlowDocument. But depending on what you are trying to do, it may be possible to play with the RichTextBox underlying FlowDocument to achieve what you want.

Comment: What I would like to have is something like a toggle beside each line. When I clock on that toggle the complete line is highlighted. Compare-Tools often do have such a functionality: you can click beside each line to mark it. Or Visual Studio has that for setting Breakpoints for example.

Comment: Ok I see what you want to do. Sadly, I have played a lot with RichTextBox and FlowDocuments and I can't see that being done easily with a RichTextBox... If I had to solve that, I would probably try to build a Control that would have one TextBox/TextBlock for each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will satisfy your needs. Please check and let me know if not works out.

```
<RichTextBox >
            <RichTextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="My Text on test" />
                        <TextBlock Text="My Text on test1" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </RichTextBox.Template>
        </RichTextBox>
```

I said that to use the richtextbox control template to achieve your requirement. Inside of the control template you can design your controls whatever they should be. A sample I placed two textboxes inside of Stackpanel. For your requirement if my guess is valid the below updated solution will help you.

```
<RichTextBox >
            <RichTextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Button Content="Control1" Width="60"/>
                            <Button Content="Control2" Width="60"/>
                            <Button Content="Control3" Width="60"/>
                            <Button Content="Control4" Width="60"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="13" Text="This is a multiline Richtextbox and I want to place a  control excactly  beside each line.  " />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </RichTextBox.Template>
        </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I didn't understand your solution, but how does this solves my problem? Just to make it clear: my example above has one RichTextBox with text which spans over multiple lines. Beside the RichTextBox I would like to have a control for each line. Just like in Visual Studio where there is a column left to the Texteditor to toggle Breakpoints.

Comment: Whow this looks very good! Instead of the TextBlock I could use another RichTextBox to be able to use formatted text, right? Can I determine the line of text within the textblock when I click on the corresponding button? E.g. when I click on Control1 change the Textcolor or Backgroundcolor of the first line of text "This is a multiline"?

Comment: Yes inside of this control template. you can do what ever you want. You might create the same number of textblock in the right side instead of the single richtexbox. Then, If you would like to change the  color when i click the 1st button it's very much easier. Please accespt as a answer if it helps you.